# Dilogarithm Identities

Tags: number-theory, special-functions

Is there a cleaner way to write:
$$
f(x) = \operatorname{Li}_2(i x) - \operatorname{Li}_2(-i x)
$$
in terms of simpler functions? I don't know enough about dilogarithms, and the basic identities I see on wikipedia are not helping me.

Comment: $Li_2(x)$ is defined as a certain power series, right? So, what power series do you get when you substitute $ix$ for $x$, substitute $-ix$ for $x$, and subtract, combining like terms?

Comment: Though we cannot reduce it to a more elementary function, there are widely used special functions that can replace $f(x)$. You may want to refer to the [Clausen function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clausen_function) or the [Legendre chi function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_chi_function).

Answer (score 4):

Actually, if you define

$$g(x) = \Im{[\text{Li}_2(i x)]}$$

then you can show using the series definition of

$$\text{Li}_2(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n^2}$$

that

$$g(x) = \int_0^x dt \frac{\arctan{t}}{t} $$

Comment: This is a named integral, the [inverse tangent integral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InverseTangentIntegral.html). (+1)

Comment: Yes, makes a lot of sense - the arctan and the log are related.  Thanks.

Comment: The arctan integral is from where the dilogarithm arose for me! So it looks like there is no nicer expression. I think there is connection of the dilogarithm to hyperbolic geometry, but I am not sure. Thank you for the help anyway!

Comment: @user66180, you should have mentioned this to begin with. :) The thing is, since some people like to keep things to the real line, they have defined the inverse tangent integrals to sidestep the use of polylogarithms of complex argument, though as you have already seen, they are intimately related in the same way that the logarithm and inverse trigonometric functions are.

Answer (score 1):

I can show you some approximations which might help:

For the case of $|x|<1$ we have that

$ i(\operatorname{Li}_2(-i x) - \operatorname{Li}_2(i x)) ≃ 2x $

For the case of $|x|\ge1$ we have that

$ i(\operatorname{Li}_2(-i x) - \operatorname{Li}_2(i x)) ≃ π\cdot log(x) $

Another good approximation for any x is

$ i(\operatorname{Li}_2(-i x) - \operatorname{Li}_2(i x)) ≃ π \cdot arcsinh(x/2) $